# html array-form gives not array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

How to send a form with inputs in a array?

```
<form action="foo.php" method="GET">
    <input name="myArray[]" value="1">
    <input name="myArray[]" value="2">
    <input name="myArray[]" value="3">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

when i click submit the url becomes `foo.php?myArray%5B%5D=1&myArray%5B%5D=2&myArray%5B%5D=3`

I want `foo.php?myArray=1+2+3` or something like this. Thanks

Comment: Everything is ok. $_GET['myArray'] will contain array.

Comment: Have you tried using POST instead?

Comment: okay so it's just the looks in the url? when i use php to get it, it will work like i want/suspect?

Comment: What `type` of input element are these? Without a defined type they will default to `text`

Comment: @RamRaider the real code is more complicated with different types, but does it matter what type? If it does I will be using `text`

Comment: I believe you should use POST as Difster already suggested. You cannot handle the url as you'd like (myArray=1+2+3) with  simple GET method to display array in a different format, unless you'll use onClick event - with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do what you are intended for or not. But here is a basic guide:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
    <input name="inp1" value="1"/>
    <input name="inp2" value="2"/>
    <input name="inp3" value="3"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

here submitted URL will look like this:
`index.php?inp1=1&inp2=2&inp3=3`

GET & POST both create an array like array('key' => 'value', 'key2' =>'value')
where keys are the names of the form fields and values are the input data.
So in the above example inp1,inp2,inp3 are the form fields name and 1,2,3 are their consecutive value

You can decode your url using [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)
In your `foo.php` you can add `return urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` to see the decoded url.
And here [url encoding reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)